# Polynomial Transformation Problem

Tags: polynomials

Find a polynomial with roots the same to those of $\frac{1}{2}x^2-\sqrt{7}x+2$ such that it has integer coefficients.

It seems that squaring leads to nothing and I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: The roots are $$x=\sqrt{7}\pm\sqrt{3}$$ Try going from there

Comment: I know that but don't know what to do with that

Comment: Does the question want the roots to be exactly the same as $\sqrt{7}\pm \sqrt{3}$, or just that $\sqrt{7}\pm \sqrt{3}$ *are* roots of the new polynomial?

Comment: they just have to be the roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the $\sqrt7$ term to the right, *then* square:
$$\frac12x^2+2=\sqrt7x$$
$$\frac14x^4+2x^2+4=7x^2$$
$$\frac14x^4-5x^2+4=0$$
$$x^4-20x^2+16=0$$